# What shape of water jet nozzle produces the least splash/spray, when firing into water?

Tags: water

I am looking for views as to what shape of nozzle orifice on a water jet produces the minimal amount of spray and splash, when pressurised water is fired through the nozzle, into a water tank?
Would a round, square, eliptical, slit, or any other shape be preferable?
Any views most welcome! Thanks!
Jamie

Comment: There's a recent paper exploring just that: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cirp.2021.04.027

Comment: Lower energy means less splash, so the real life answer is to just make the nozzle as big as possible to turn the jet into a slow stream, or use a fog nozzle.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this recent article](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cirp.2021.04.027), a bundle of cylindrical tubes is best for producing laminar flow. One idea is that a cylinder will have the smallest surface area relative to volume throwing through it, such that it will impart the least resistance (through friction) to the water.